# Is my tv about to fall off?

Tags: drywall, walls, mounting, television

This has happened to my wall where my tv mount is installed [image]

Comment: Possible.  Would take tv down and move the mount to screw into the studs.

Comment: What @crip659 said. Though I’d upgrade to “probably”.

Comment: You'd have to tell us more about what we're looking at here.

Comment: Looks pretty iffy to me.

Comment: I’ve unscrewed the tv

Comment: I would upgrade that *'possibly'* to a *'likely'* if you had kept it up there. What's the thickness of the drywall? Did you use drywall plugs? What's the weight of the TV?

Comment: that looks a lot like the kind of mount that must be attached to the wall structure (like to a stud), there are some kinds that can be attached to drywall only, but not that kind.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the mount isn’t in a stud. If possible, aesthetically, get that mount screwed into a stud before the drywall pulls out in the current spot.

Comment: I’ve unscrewed the tv. The person who installed it said they can reinstall it but this time there will be a wooden block on the wall which the tv will then be mounted on is this a good solution? I must add i always pull my tv out of my wall as I use it in bed. The guy who installed it said this is the reason this bulge has happened

Comment: No, that's what articulated mounts are meant to be able to do, so the peron who installed it did a poor job of installing it, and is now trying to make you think their incompetence is your fault for using the mount to do what it was meant to do.

Comment: If it’s installed in drywall only, not in an actual wood stud behind drywall, it will not last very long, especially if you’re constantly pulling it out. Regardless of drywall anchors used, there’s only so much 1/2” of gypsum board can hold. He suggested a wooden block which I presume would be screwed into studs at each end of the block, and then the mount screwed to the block. This will make it much stronger. But if it’s possible to move the mount left or right some, then you can avoid the wooden block altogether and have the mount itself screwed into a stud in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. So would you say the wooden block method is a viable solution if it’s not possible to have the mount directly screwed into a stud? Would this cause any problems down the line like what has happened now (wall bulge)? Thanks

Comment: It’s a viable and very strong solution so long as the block itself is screwed into studs at each end which would mean you’d need a 16” block to span the space between both studs. It’s not a very good solution if the block itself isn’t anchored into studs. Such a solution is better than what you have because the block would distribute the load across a wider area, but it would not be nearly as strong as a block anchored to the studs.

Comment: @Shahek  Studs are usually place about 16 inches apart, so at most you would have to move the mount about 8 inches, if in the centre of two studs.

Comment: As this is a single point mount i would consider moving it slightly, worse case would be 8 inches, but you may find it is only and inch or so off. Get it in a stud you dont need unsightly board. Ask the installer to locate the stud so you can access where the tv would sit if moved so you can decide

Comment: I will ask him to screw the mount into a stud if possible thanks

Comment: @Shahek I would leave out the 'if possible'!